# From gpx to csv file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, xml

```
<wpt lat="1.345529841" lon="103.7577152"><time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time</wpt> 
<wpt lat="1.345529841" lon="103.7577152"><time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt> 
<wpt lat="1.3982529841" lon="103.90877152"><time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt>
```

I have a file like having the above lines which needed to be converted into

```
         1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
         1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
         1.3982529841,103.90877152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed` to strip out the characters you don't want:

```
sed 's/[^0-9.T:-]\+/,/g;s/T/ /;s/^,\|,$//g' file
```

`s/[^0-9.T:-]\+/,/g` is replacing unwanted characters with a comma

`s/T/ /` is replacing the character `T` with a space

`s/^,\|,$//g` is removing the first and last comma

Comment: Yours is ok but comma will not come.We have to add it by ourselves

Comment: didn't notice the  comma, answer updated

Comment: oliv everything is fine but instead of 103.75... in the second column ,I am getting 103,75.(For everything in column 2) Anything wrong in the code ?

Comment: look at the updated answer, it should the solve the comma/dot notation

Comment: Yeah it does :)

Comment: Sorry, I know this is technically correct, but ... `sed` is a really awful tool for XML parsing. `XML` is contextual, and regular expressions are not.

Answer (score 3):

[GPX is an XML format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format), so you can't use `awk` or `sed` to parse it reliably.

Instead, use something like [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) (assuming the XML document is well-formed and contains no errors):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//wpt' \
          -v '@lat' -o ',' \
          -v '@lon' -o ',' \
          -v 'time' -nl data.gpx
1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01T00:00:00Z
1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01T00:00:00Z
1.3982529841,103.90877152,2010-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Alternatively:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//wpt' -v 'concat(@lat, ",", @lon, ",", time)' -nl data.wpx
```

---

You could also use `xq` (part of `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```
$ xq -r '.. | .wpt? // empty | .[] | map(values) | @csv' data.gpx
"1.345529841","103.7577152","2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"1.345529841","103.7577152","2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"1.3982529841","103.90877152","2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

This finds all `wpt` nodes and extracts the values of all attributes and sub-nodes, and creates CSV output from these.

If you need to rearrange the columns or cherry-pick the values you use for each column, you could also do

```
$ xq -r '.. | .wpt? // empty | .[] | [."@lat", ."@lon", .time] | @csv' data.gpx
"1.345529841","103.7577152","2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"1.345529841","103.7577152","2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
"1.3982529841","103.90877152","2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, please - don't use a regular expression based solution, like `awk` or `sed`.

`XML` is contextual, where regular expressions are not - [so they can NEVER work properly, they're only at best a bit of a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

But XML does have a solution to this problem - it's called `xpath`, that lets you 'search' in a contextual way.

So to take your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $xml = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile('your_file.xml'); 

foreach my $wpt ( $xml -> get_xpath('//wpt') ) {
   print join ",", $wpt -> att('lat'), 
                   $wpt -> att('lon'),
                   $wpt -> first_child_text('time'), "\n";
}
```

Which gives the desired result, but it will also handle a variety of otherwise perfectly valid and semantically identical forms of your XML.

Like indented:

```
<xml>
  <wpt lat="1.345529841" lon="103.7577152">
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="1.345529841" lon="103.7577152">
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
  </wpt>
  <wpt lat="1.3982529841" lon="103.90877152">
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
  </wpt>
</xml>
```

All on a single line:

```
<xml><wpt lat="1.345529841" lon="103.7577152"><time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt><wpt lat="1.345529841" lon="103.7577152"><time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt><wpt lat="1.3982529841" lon="103.90877152"><time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt></xml>
```

Another style of indenting:

```
<xml>
  <wpt
      lat="1.345529841"
      lon="103.7577152">
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
  </wpt>
  <wpt
      lat="1.345529841"
      lon="103.7577152">
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
  </wpt>
  <wpt
      lat="1.3982529841"
      lon="103.90877152">
    <time>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time>
  </wpt>
</xml>
```

Or even:

```
<xml
><wpt
lat="1.345529841"
lon="103.7577152"
><time
>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt><wpt
lat="1.345529841"
lon="103.7577152"
><time
>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt><wpt
lat="1.3982529841"
lon="103.90877152"
><time
>2010-01-01T00:00:00Z</time></wpt></xml>
```

These are all semantically identical, and *should* be parsed the same way. Hopefully it's fairly clear that a regular expression to do this is a LOT more complicated than just using an XML parser.

For the sake of being concise though:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -0777 -e 'XML::Twig->new(twig_handlers=>{wpt=>sub{print join ",", $_->att("lat", $_->att("lon"),$_->first_child_text("time"), "\n" }})->parse(<>)'
```

Answer (score 1):

this answer is Based on the input given...

```
awk -F"[<>\"]" '{print $3,$5,$9}' OFS=, input.txt | sed "s/[TZ]/ /g"
1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.3982529841,103.90877152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
```

---

```
awk -F"[<>\"]" '{gsub(/T|Z/," ",$9);print $3,$5,$9}' OFS=, input.txt
```

Comment: Itruns for  quite a long time and does not seems to be finishing even for small file

Comment: what is your OS ? provide the exact command you typed in your terminal

Comment: seems, you missed some double quotes in the command and it expects to close and waits for long time...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `f.xml` is our input (a valid xml):

```
$ perl -MXML::DT -E 'dt("f.xml",
                         time=>sub{$a=father;
                                   $c =~ s/[TZ]/ /g;
                                   say "$a->{lat},$a->{lon},$c"}
                       )'
```

- `-MXML::DT` load XML::DT module (xml down translator)
- `dt( file, time => sub{....})` : parse file and every time we see a `time` execute the correspondent sub
- `$a=father`  : get the attributes from father
- `$c` : is the current element content

Warning: I am one of the authors of XML::DT (install with `cpan XML::DT`)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/[^0-9.:-]/ /g" j.txtK| sed -r "s/\s+/ /g"| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"|awk 'OFS=","{print $1,$2,$3" " $4}'
```

output

```
1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.345529841,103.7577152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.3982529841,103.90877152,2010-01-01 00:00:00
```