# replace full stop by comma

Tags: linux, awk, sed

For the below values I have to replace the second and fourth "."  by  "," in the below file

input

```
1.351364711.103.7319660.2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.345529841.103.7372875.2010-01-01 00:00:49
1.342955629.103.7455272.2010-01-01 00:01:42
1.339694956.103.7520503.2010-01-01 00:02:28
```

desired intermediate  output

```
    1.351364711,103.7319660,2010-01-01 00:00:00
    1.345529841,103.7372875,2010-01-01 00:00:49
    1.342955629,103.7455272,2010-01-01 00:01:42
    1.339694956,103.7520503,2010-01-01 00:02:28
```

I know `awk gsub(/./,",")` this replaces everything by comma.But I only need the columns to be seperated by "," .  I also wanted to switch the third column in the first place after this.

desired final output

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00,1.351364711,103.7319660
2010-01-01 00:00:49,1.345529841,103.7372875
2010-01-01 00:01:42,1.342955629,103.7455272
2010-01-01 00:02:28,1.339694956,103.7520503
```

Comment: So, the 2nd and 4th periods become commas?

Comment: Yup exactly the second and fourth becomes commas

Comment: If that's the case, the question should clearly say so.

Comment: final expected output is not clear, I think you want a space to separate field after time.. `awk -F. '{print $5 " " $1 "." $2 "," $3 "." $4}'`

Comment: duplicate ? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343636/from-gpx-to-csv-file/343645#343645

Comment: @Kamaraj It is not a duplicate.That question deals with the conversion of gpx to csv and this one is more towards the re-arangement of the CSV columns.

Comment: @Sundeep I edited the output.It should be clear now I guess.Not a space a comma

Comment: @RKR why don't you post a original file contents and the command you used to extract the required fields. so we can offer a slight changes in your command itself.

Comment: @Kamaraj I do not wanna make the question more complex.I think the way now is good and understandable to others.Otherwise it links with the previous question and will be more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bash-4.1$ cat file
1.351364711.103.7319660.2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.345529841.103.7372875.2010-01-01 00:00:49
1.342955629.103.7455272.2010-01-01 00:01:42
1.339694956.103.7520503.2010-01-01 00:02:28

bash-4.1$ awk -F. '{print $NF,$1"."$2,$3"."$4}' OFS=, file
2010-01-01 00:00:00,1.351364711,103.7319660
2010-01-01 00:00:49,1.345529841,103.7372875
2010-01-01 00:01:42,1.342955629,103.7455272
2010-01-01 00:02:28,1.339694956,103.7520503
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\./,/4; s/\./,/2' file
1.351364711,103.7319660,2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.345529841,103.7372875,2010-01-01 00:00:49
1.342955629,103.7455272,2010-01-01 00:01:42
1.339694956,103.7520503,2010-01-01 00:02:28
```

This first replaces the 4th dot with a comma, then the 2nd.

We could have done the substitutions in the opposite order too, but since replacing the 2nd dot removes a dot from the line, the dot originally being 4th becomes the 3rd dot:

```
$ sed 's/\./,/2; s/\./,/3' file
1.351364711,103.7319660,2010-01-01 00:00:00
1.345529841,103.7372875,2010-01-01 00:00:49
1.342955629,103.7455272,2010-01-01 00:01:42
1.339694956,103.7520503,2010-01-01 00:02:28
```

The `s/.../.../n` syntax (where `n` is a digit) substitutes the n:th matching occurrence on a line.

Moving the last column to the front may be done with

```
s/^\(.*\),\([^,]*\)/\2,\1/
```

I.e., match stuff from the start of the line up to a comma, then the comma, then stuff that contains no more commas.

So the full command may be

```
$ sed 's/\./,/4; s/\./,/2; s/^\(.*\),\([^,]*\)/\2,\1/' file
2010-01-01 00:00:00,1.351364711,103.7319660
2010-01-01 00:00:49,1.345529841,103.7372875
2010-01-01 00:01:42,1.342955629,103.7455272
2010-01-01 00:02:28,1.339694956,103.7520503
```